# iniciar sesión en un router mikrotik via telnet desde la API

Tags: php, api, router, telnet

mi problema es que puedo iniciar sesión vía API a un router mikrotik con una ip publica,
pero una vez que estoy dentro no se como iniciar sesión con telnet para acceder a un router con ip privada, me podrían ayudar, adjunto el código.

```
if ($API->connect( '40.49.10.2', 'admin', 'admin')) {
// hasta aqui no hay problema, puedo trabajar con el router.


   $API->write('/system/telnet',false);

   $API->write("=address=" . '192.168.10.1',true);
   $READ = $API->read();
  $API->write("=Login=" . "admin", true);
  $READ = $API->read();
   $API->write("=Password=" . 'admin',true);
   $READ = $API->read();
   $API->write('/system/identity/print');
   $READ = $API->read();
```

// mi problema es como pasar los parametros de sesion via API